# How to prevent the browser from canceling downloads from the same url

Tags: file, http, url, download

I hope somebody can help me.

We have a self written http server which is used as a proxy to download logfiles from other devices (which also have httpservers).

We have a webpage which lists those device. Each device has its own downloadbutton, which is a link to the same url, just with different query params (e.g. /logfile.log?device=12345, /logfile.log?device=67890, ..."

The problem is, that those devices do not respond immediately, but collect data for a long time (e.g. 50 seconds) and then send data.

My problem now is, that if the user clicks on the first button and then on the second, before the first device sent data, the download is canceled by the browser. Also the download window (where the user can selects if he wants to open or save the file) is display as soon as the first bytes are received.

The query params are completely ignored, the browser seems to think that it downloads the same file and therefore it skips the previous download.

I think this problem should be the same as if you want to download something from a database server which needs some time to respond and then try to download something from the same link. It should also skip the first download?

I already tried to modify the HTTP proxy server so that it responds with a head which tells the browser by the content-disposition that a file with a specific name is downloaded, but no bytes from the file right at the beginning. Me hope was, that this is sufficient to trigger the download window and stop the browser canceling the download. But unfortunately it doees not work.

If I send just some random bytes, it works as expected, but of course the file is not the original one.

I already tried to use a form submit button with get and post instead of a href, but it doesn't work.

Can anybody give me a hind, how to fix it? Of course I would like to fix it in the server, but if there is a workaround on clientside, this would be also fine for me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are the files being downloaded? Is it a javascript call, or are they being downloaded by the browser?

Comment: I tried to download the files from the server with a href link the user can click on (with a nice icon) and I also tried it with a submit button inside a form.

The proxy http server has also a self written http client which basically opens a socket and downloads the file from the device with a http get. Then it reads the data from from the socket and sends them out as chunked data.

By the way, how can I enter empty lines here? I tried it with shift+enter, but when I click save, everything is in one line

Comment: No idea anyone? I also tried adding * followed by a randomstring before the ? in the url, but browser also canceled the download